# VendorCentral Ruby X12 EDI: found "1~" instead of segment identifier

Tags: ruby, x12

I am new to X12 EDI and slightly confused. End goal is extracting the data to our database(Or a CSV).

I'm using Ruby library [STUPIDEDI](https://github.com/kputnam/stupidedi) to parse some X12 Files. I am not getting beyond this error in the title.

**Example-830-File:**

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*CHEESE         *12*VENDOR ISA     *160321*1828*U*00400*000004970*0*T*>~
GS*PS*CHEESE*2018584966*20160321*1828*4970*X*004010~
ST*830*0001~
BFR*00*Forecast ID**DL*A*20131229*20140323*20140104****MN~
REF*IA*Vendor Code~
N1*DU*CHEESE US*15*1526642~
N1*VN*Vendor Name*92*123456789~
LIN*1*UP*123456789123456*B123456789~
UIT*EA~
FST*0*D*W*20131229~
FST*0*D*W*20140105~
FST*0*D*W*20140112~
FST*0*D*W*20140119~
FST*0*D*W*20140126~
FST*0*D*W*20140202~
FST*0*D*W*20140209~
FST*0*D*W*20140216~
FST*0*D*W*20140223~
FST*0*D*W*20140302~
FST*0*D*W*20140309~
FST*0*D*W*20140316~
FST*0*D*W*20140323~
SE~1~0001~
GE~1~1~
IEA~1~000000001~
```

**Code:**

```
config = Stupidedi::Config.contrib
parser = Stupidedi::Builder::StateMachine.build(config)

input = File.open(file_path_to_example_830)
# Reader.build accepts IO (File), String, and DelegateInput
parser, result = parser.read(Stupidedi::Reader.build(input))

# Raises exception in title
if result.fatal?
  result.explain { |reason| raise reason + " at #{result.position.inspect}" }
end

# Hoping to Print some information
parser.first
  .flatmap { |m| m.find(:GS) }
  .flatmap { |m| m.find(:ST) }
  .tap do |m|
  el(m.find(:N1, "PR"), 2) { |e| puts "Payer: #{e}" }
  el(m.find(:N1, "PE"), 2) { |e| puts "Payee: #{e}" }
end
  .flatmap { |m| m.find(:LX) }
  .flatmap { |m| m.find(:CLP) }
  .flatmap { |m| m.find(:NM1, "QC") }
  .tap { |m| el(m, 3, 4) { |l, f| puts "Patient: #{l}, #{f}" } }
```

**Its raising an error:**

```
 RuntimeError:
       found "1~" instead of segment identifier at file /Users/foo/Documents/dev/project/public/X12_830_FORECAST/X12_Example_830.txt, line 23, column 4
```

To clarify error points to `line 23, column 4` which is `SE~1~0001~`

Comment: I found this https://github.com/kputnam/stupidedi/blob/master/lib/stupidedi/contrib/004010/guides/PS830.rb but not sure how to plug in?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the input file is invalid. The last 3 segments have `~` instead of `*` as element separators, so it's recognising each element as a separate segment.

Those segments should be:

```
SE*21*0001~
GE*1*4970~
IEA*1*000004970~
```

Answer (score 0):

The number after SE~ (called SE01) must be the "Number Of Included Segments", which is, in your case if I am counting well, equal to **21**.

Have a try with `SE~21~0001~` and let me know.